# How to configure autocompletion so that it replaces everything until non-word-char?

Tags: autocompletion

I'm using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd> to do auto-completion when editing - since years.

One things that annoys me (and now I want the solution) is that the completion is not replaced characters until the next non-letter-characters (everything else than `0-9a-zA-Z_` for me).

For exemple, I have the following line:

```
auto a = obj->getSomething()
```

I want to change the called method to `getString`. I'll put my cursor right behind the `S` and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd> until the right method appears and I select it with <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. Here is what I end up with

```
auto a = obj->getStringomethingNumber()
```

Ideally vim would have replaced everything up to `(` with the method-name, so to get it directly, without have to do <kbd>dw</kbd> manually.

```
auto a = obj->getString()
```

How can achieve this?

Comment: Starting on the S, hit l (right char) ce and then Ctrl n

Comment: Thanks, didn't know `ce`, but how to combine it with CTRL-n, or maybe  replacing CTRL-n. And while being in insert-mode.

Comment: I think youre confusing a bit the vim philosophy. I see two steps here: changing the method name (leaving us in insert mode) and then using completion. Hence i suggest normal c{motion} and then hit your completion. Navigate and edit in normal. Type in insert.

Comment: When hitting CTRL-N I'm in insert-mode, that would make it: `ESC`-`ce`-`CTRL-N`. Which I could map into a shortcut - maybe replace CTRL-N itself with it. That's maybe the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: My point is why are you navigating to the S in insert mode. Thats what normal mode is *for*

Comment: Because I'm editing code. Maybe it's a habit... hmm, no it's not a habit. It's how I work. And isn't the flexibility why we are using vi(m)? If I wanted to use something where other's decide how to use it, I'd chose something else, with less configuration power. Thanks for your hint with `ce`